# Trailing slash in the URL for robots.txt

Tags: django, seo, robots.txt

I'm developing a website using Django, and Django really likes its trailing slashes so it's easier to give in than to go against it. I planning to also serve the robots.txt file via Django, so I'm wondering:

Would it matter for search bots if robots.txt file was located at `example.com/robots.txt/` and `example.com/robots.txt` would redirect to the URL with the trailing slash? Or does this make no difference at all?

UPDATE:
According to [Robots.txt Specifications](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt#handling-http-result-codes), at least five redirect hops are allowed, so I'm in the clear.

Comment: Personally I prefer `/robots.txt` to `/robots.txt/` (because it has an extension), even in a Django app where other URLs like `/login/` and `/accounts/` all have trailing slashes.

Comment: @Alasdair this endpoint is for machines to consume, I'm only worrying about whether they can access it like that and not about aesthetics. And it seems like they can (see the update I've made).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance. Next time, please heed [the warning](https://imgur.com/a/enYwabk) and avoid asking non-programming related SEO related questions here.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt
The URL for the robots.txt file is - like other URLs - case-sensitive so you should use robots.txt only without trailing slash (and redirection).

Comment: Thanks for the link. According to the information there, up to 5 redirect hops are allowed. So I'm in the clear :)

Comment: If you edit your answer to reflect this info, I'll mark it as accepted, otherwise it's a little bit misleading right now (even though really helpful).